# DataGridView EndEdit VB

Tags: vb.net

Now, I use EndEdit in Leave EventArgs, but when I use EndEdit, I cannot close my form. Does anyone know the reason ?

Below is my leave function:

```
 Private Sub dgv_Leave(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgv.Leave
            Me.dgv.EndEdit()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to solve the EndEdit Problem. Then, I could end editing correctly and I could close my form successfully.

http://dobon.net/vb/bbs/log3-35/21499.html

```
Public Class Form4_4
    Inherits Form

    Dim WithEvents m_dgv As New DataGridView()
    Dim WithEvents m_editingcontrol As Control

    Private Sub Form4_4_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        m_dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        m_dgv.RowCount = 10
        m_dgv.ColumnCount = 3
        Me.Controls.Add(m_dgv)
    End Sub

    Private Sub m_dgv1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles m_dgv.CellEndEdit
        Me.m_editingcontrol = Nothing ' ←　Cancel EventHandler Here
        Console.WriteLine("CellEndEdit")
    End Sub

    Private Sub m_dgv_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles m_dgv.EditingControlShowing
        Console.WriteLine("EditingControlShowing")
        Me.m_editingcontrol = e.Control ' ←　Register EventHandler Here
    End Sub

    Private Sub m_editingcontrol_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles m_editingcontrol.PreviewKeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Then
            Me.m_dgv.EndEdit()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to some validation error might be present in your DataGridView. You have to check that `dataGridView.EndEdit()` succeeded and you may also need to check your Cell and RowValidating events if present.